# How can i get client country without using any web service or without any prompt message asking for location?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get client's country location without using any web service or without any prompt message asking for location?

Geo-location permissions are sometimes denied by user.
Web services are not dependable because the server can be down at times.

Comment: You cannot do that, if not only because any service that might allow it would certainly constitute an "api".

Comment: Yes we can, by using hreflang